# How exactly does the placement of parenthesis change a material conditional in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-languages

I noticed that with exportation P → (Q → R) is equivalent to (P ∧ Q) → R. This got me confused about the difference between P→ (Q → R) and (P → Q) → R. What exactly do the parentheses do to change the meaning or are they equivalent?

Comment: Note:  $(8\div4)\div2\ne8\div(4\div2)$

Comment: Apart from calculating the truth tables of each proposition, one other way to start to understand is to read them aloud, reading the parentheses as if they were commas.

Comment: $P\to(Q\to R)$ is “If $P$, then (if $Q$, then $R$)”; which is why it is equivalent to “if $P$ and $Q$, then $R$”. Whereas $(P\to Q)\to R$ means “if $P$ implies $Q$, then $R$”, which is something entirely different. Compare “If it’s sunny, then (if it is not too warm then I’ll go running)” to “If, (being sunny implies it is not too warm), then I’ll go running.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a truth table.  Note that if $Q$ is false, $P\rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$ is always true, because the consequent is true.  On the other hand $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow R$ is false if $P,Q,R$ are all false because the antecedent is true and the consequent is false.

Answer (score 0):

Contraposition law says that:  $(X \rightarrow Y) \equiv ( \neg Y \rightarrow\neg X)$ .

---

$P → (Q → R) \equiv \neg (Q\rightarrow R) \rightarrow\neg P\equiv (Q\land\neg R)\rightarrow\neg P$

So, it means that $\neg R$ conjoined with $Q$ is sufficient for $P$ to be false.

But

$(P\rightarrow Q) \rightarrow R \equiv \neg R \rightarrow \neg ( P \rightarrow Q)\equiv \neg R \rightarrow (P\land \neg Q)$

So it means that $\neg R$ is sufficient for $P$ to be true.